# vba sub slow after first execution

Tags: vba, excel

I have seen others with similar questions with no real answer.

When i run a sub that imports data onto 3 worksheets and then compiles a 4th sheet from those 3 worksheets it runs in just over 17secs.

The main part of the 17 secs is writing  10,000 rows (26 columns each) of data to the output sheet in 13.86sec doing just over 720 rows a second.

The problem arises when i run this sub again without closing excel ,  it takes forever!   the import stage is no slower but writing to the output sheets slows down to a consistently poor 17 rows a second.   (35X decrease in speed)

i have tested every thing i know about VBA and i cannot find out why this is.

the start of the Sub always erases each sheet using

```
If sh.AutoFilterMode Then sh.AutoFilterMode = False
sh.Columns.Hidden = False
sh.Rows.Hidden = False
sh.Cells.Clear  
sh.Cells.Delete
```

i have always used this to clear sheets and never had an issue,   until i found a fix for my problem , by actually deleting the 4 sheets and recreating them ,this fixes the terrible slowdown in speed.

What is left behind on my sheets that the above code is not removing and causing this slowdown issue?

I have also left the sheets full of data and saved and closed the workbook, and i still get perfect performance on the first run after opening excel so its not the actual data on the sheets.

NB - The rest of the code is just standard loops and writing to cells and i am 100% sure that its not the problem with this issue

Comment: If you are using xl2010 and earlier, run it after saving the Workspace. The Workspace was abandoned in xl2013 with multiple workbook windows.

Comment: How the hell?!  can you explain why that worked?!

Comment: VBA has historically been reluctant to release memory; this can be verified with something as simple as the TaskManager, Processes tab. Some internal mechanism is not releasing the memory until you save the workspace; it doesn't by saving the workbook.

Comment: If you want to flesh this out to a self-answer, I'll upvote it and you can accept it as the answer after 48 hours.

Comment: So this is not an issue in versions >xl2010 or there is no fix for it in >xl2010 ?   iv spent days looking online for an answer and never read 1 post about saving the workspace to release memory

Comment: From my own experience, it is not an issue with 64-bit Office installations (VB7). That *should* cover 2010 and a significant portion of 2007 but the default installation for both of those was 32-bit, not 64-bit. Even xl2003 had a 64-bit install somewhere (IIRC). That isn't to say that xl2013 and xl2016/Office 365 do not have 32-bit installs; I know they do because I keep both on an older laptop for testing purposes. In any event, I discovered this when making massive imports of US GSA data and I've tried to proselytize its practice. Sorry, cannot pinpoint *exactly* why it works.

Comment: I am not sure of the active community members on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) differs from the one here. Yet, you might want to give it a try and re-post your question there. It seems that you have working code which merely requires improvements Code Review is where they handle existing / working code and do their upmost to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, but I doubt i can get the guys in Microsoft to visit Code Review to learn how to release memory after use!

Comment: There's currently [361 VBA questions at Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba). Feel free to give it a shot if you got working code which you need to get reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

It dates back a long time, but anyway: Today I have faced the same issue with my VBA-tool (Excel 2010, invoking via UF, Import of > 40000 lines of data and performing of some calculations):
-> Runtime at 1st run: 40sec and 11MIN at 2nd run (after the UF was closed and opened again). I was able to solve the issue by erasing explicitly the arrays I have used in the code via the "Erase" command and setting the WorkBook-object to "Nothing" explicitly before the UF is closed.

**Example:**

*Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
Logger_End

```
    Erase allAsmFileREVsArray()
    Erase allAsmFileURLsArray()
    
    Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
End If
```

End Sub*

Maybe it helps...

Answer (score 0):

based on you description, i think the possible solutions as below.

1. put `application.screenupdating = false` at the first of your sub, and `application.screenupdating = true` before exit sub.
2. put `application.calculation = xlCalculationManual` at first of your sub, and `application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` before exit sub.
3. Using array variable.  If you want to input a 100000 x 26 to range("A1:Z100000"), the normal and **slow** way as below

   ```
   for i = 1 to 100000
       for j = 1 to 26
           cells(i,j).value = 123
       next j
   next i
   ```

   the **fast** way is

   ```
   dim ary(100000 - 1, 26 -1) as variant
   'make an array
   for i = lbound(ary, 1) to ubound(ary, 1)
       for j = lbound(ary, 2) to ubound(ary, 2)
          ary(i, j) = 123
       next j
   next i

   range("a1").resize(ubound(ary, 1) - lbound(ary, 1) + 1, ubound(ary, 2) - lbound(ary, 2) +1).value = ary
   ```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue being discussed  and I have this. We are talking about running this code a second time and the sudden decrease in speed , due to memory not being cleared from the worksheets -  saving the workspace or deleting the sheets solves the issue.

Comment: @StevenMartin Do you try to set the `application.screenupdating` and `application.calculation` properties?  If so,  I am sorry that I cannot help you.

Comment: Yes I have this in my code - again we are not talking about speed -  were talking about the performance of the same code after the first execution